# What is the issue with my pipe only tee is working?

Tags: c, linux, posix

I am having an issue with piping to a child of a fork.
Only tee seems to work.

I create a pipe call execvp and do a fork
Data is passed to the child through a pipe.

It work with tee any thing else throws a EPIPE error.
hits "the lost connection" below.

works
when app_argv is set to
tee /home/projects/teeout.wav | cat > /home/projects/catout.wav

does not work
when app_argv is set to
cat | tee /home/projects/teeout.wav

Whats is the issue because both the above should collect from stdin?
So what the difference?

```
pid = fork();
if (pid == 0)
{
    // Child
    dup2(pipefd[0],   STDIN_FILENO);

    execvp(app, app_argv);

    exit(1);
}


....

int result = write(pipefd[1], data, datalen);
    if (result < 0) {
    if (errno == EPIPE) {
        LOG("lost connection\n");
        close(pipefd[1]); 
        pipefd[1] = -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you are adding `|` and `>` to `app_argv`. These are shell features that only shells understand. You can not pass `|` to `tee` or `cat` to pipe something.

Comment: After `dup2(pipefd[0],   STDIN_FILENO);` you should use `close(pipefd[0]); close(pipefd[1]);` so that the unused pipe file descriptors are properly closed.  **Rule of thumb**: If you [`dup2()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup2.html) one end of a pipe to standard input or standard output, close both of the original file descriptors from `pipe()` as soon as possible. In particular, that means before using any of the [`exec*()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execvp.html) family of functions.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it.